# Display Swagger UI on Flask without any hookups

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui

Anyone know of a way I can serve a swagger UI `.yml` file on on flask without creating or hooking up the API? I just want to show the swagger file on the website so people can see how to use the API, but I don't want to create an API or hook anything up because the API is private so it can't be called anyway.

The API is from AWS API Gateway so I can't hook anything up with flask.

I looked into [connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) but I need to hook up my API methods to use it which won't work.

I can using the openapi editor to convert the api specification to html then serve the html but I want to try to use the nice layout that swagger ui provides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swagger has a published example in the [`dist` folder](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/v3.22.1/dist) of the project.

The browser ready javascript bundles are [available in `unpkg` or directly via `cloudflare CDN`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/installation.md#unpkg) and can be served directly from there.

In your use case, you can write a template file similar to the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder without setting up an additional build process for the Swagger UI bundle for your flask project.

Your template will look as follows where you replace the value for `url` with the URL to the `yaml` file containing your API definition:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.22.1/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.22.1/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/3.22.1/swagger-ui.css" /> -->
    <title>Swagger</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
          SwaggerUIBundle({
            url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml",
            dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
            presets: [
              SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
              SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
            ],
            layout: "StandaloneLayout"
          })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the [Swagger UI npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui), which publishes a JavaScript bundle that you could serve with the spec document.

You may have to do some minor manipulation by loading the spec file into the UI object.

## Edit

I found some code for when I did something exactly the same. I created a JavaScript file that would load the spec from the server and display it with the `SwaggerUI` package, replacing a designated HTML tag. This also utilized a library to parse the YAML into JSON.

I used webpack to bundle everything up, but you could potentially use another web bundler.

**JavaScript: `index.js`**

```
const jsYAML = require('js-yaml');
const SwaggerUI = require('swagger-ui');

function httpGetAsync(url, callback) {
    let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    };

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function parseYamlSpec(yaml) {
    try {
        return jsYAML.safeLoad(yaml);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error parsing OpenAPI YAML to JavaScript object');
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }
}

function displayOpenApiSpec() {
    httpGetAsync('./openapi.yaml', function (yamlSpec) {
        SwaggerUI({
            dom_id: '#openapi',
            spec: parseYamlSpec(yamlSpec)
        })
    });
}

displayOpenApiSpec();
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger Doc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swagger-ui.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="openapi"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also grabbed the CSS file from the SwaggerUI package and served that as well. That is a necessity to make it look pretty and functional.

## Edit 2

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "sdk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "js-yaml": "^3.12.0",
    "swagger-ui": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Given that you have [`Node.js` and `npm`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) installed, you can use the above `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` files, and run the following two commands from the working directory:

```
npm install
npm build
```

#### What this is doing

Essentially, you want to serve an HTML file, a JavaScript bundle, and a CSS stylesheet that will work to load your Swagger spec into the DOM, style it nicely, and use the SwaggerUI library to make it interactive.

With the given JavaScript file, this will not work in the browser because it uses `Node.js` style `require` to import the two needed libraries. But webpack will be able to replace these with the actual JavaScript libraries in-line, and "minify" the code so that it is smaller in file size.

To do that, you need to install all of those libraries (using `npm`, the Node Package Manager), as well as webpack (along with its command line interface), and then run webpack so that it will bundle everything up for you.

The `package.json` file lists all of those needed libraries plus webpack and defines a "script" for you to run the webpack command. By running `npm install`, `npm` will install everything for you in a local folder called `node_modules`.

Then, running `npm build`, `Node.js` will execute the `webpack` command which will do all the bundling and create the output file `bundle.js` (which is referenced in the HTML file above).

Once this is all done, you can add `index.html`, `bundle.js`, `swagger-ui.css` (which I copied out of the SwaggerUI directory in `node_modules`), and your Swagger spec to your publicly served files on your server.

Comment: I have seen that link several times in my search but it is not very useful, to me it just looks like a nasty package I need to muddle through, no usage guide or anything. Do you have an article that explains the process? I am not a web developer so without something to read through I don't have the skill to use the packages with no documentation.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how would use web pack to package everything together? I don't know JavaScript or anything regarding packaging web applications so I don't know what I need to do to get the solution to work.  I am more of an application developer than a web developer.

Comment: I added a lengthy explanation. And this whole ordeal is unnecessary if you go with Oluwafemi Sule's solution. I just wanted to give you info on what I did previously.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will look at his solution first but I just wanted to say thanks.